# How to open all files with some specific extension(prefix in name) in fortran ?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77, fortran95

I want to read data from some files in Fortran, I can do that when the file names have a regular order. but now it's not regular, although all have same prefix for example : Fix001, Fix002, Fix023, Fix432, ...

I want the program get the prefix from the user and open all the files in a loop, read the data and write them in a single file. 
any idea ? 
Thanks.

```
PROGRAM Output
Implicit none
Integer ::n=5        !number of files
Integer ::nn=50  !number of rows in each file
Integer ::i,j
Real,Dimension(:),Allocatable::t,x,y,z
Character(len=12)::TD 

Open(11,file='outputX.txt')
Allocate (t(1000),x(1000),y(1000),z(1000)) 

 j=0
Do i=1,n
    Write(TD,10)i 
    Write(*,*)TD 
    Open(1,file=TD) 
        Read(1,*)(t(j),x(j),j=1,nn)
        Write(11,20)(x(j),j=1,nn)
 j=j+1
Enddo

10  Format('100',i3.3,'') 
20 Format(<nn>E25.8E3)

 Deallocate(x,y,z,t) 
 END PROGRAM Output
```

Comment: FYI `integer :: n = 5` is not equivalent to `integer :: n; n = 5` but `integer, save :: n = 5`. This surprises a lot of new Fortraners.

Comment: confess, i didn't know, but now it works anyway ;)

Comment: What is the particular problem you are seeing with that program?

Comment: You really don't need all those language tags, and in particular your code isn't Fortran 77.  If you have a specific language revision you need to target you can mention that explicitly.  Even Fortran 95 is very superseded.

Comment: This has no problem and work, but just until the file numbers are in order, i mean for example it reads the files: Fix001, Fix002, Fix003... but if this order break some where program will close.

Comment: Do you have an upper bound on the number of files to be opened.  That is, if you just skip the filename if the file doesn't exist, that's fine?  Or you want to query the filesystem for those files matching the pattern?

Comment: In fact i'm a science PhD and i'm never expert in programming. i just need that to do so duties for me ! so i start writing with my logic and searching for solution whenever there is some problem.I have no idea about most of programming rules!

Comment: Yes, There is upper bound and it can be good idea, because there isn't big gap between numbers. it could be maximum of 100 numbers in each gap, i don't know if we skip that, how could it affect the analysis time and so on. maximum number of files could be about 2000

Comment: You can read up on `iostat=` in the `open` statement to not fail if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Not related to your question, but choosing a `unit` identifier of less than 10 (as you do in `Open(1,file=TD)`) is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do have an upper limit, you can try to open the file and test with the `iostat` parameter whether that was successful. If it wasn't, you skip the file.

This is an example that reads only the first integer variable from a file and appends it to the output file:

```
program read_files
    implicit none
    integer :: i, d
    integer :: ioerr
    character(len=len("FixXXX.txt")) :: fname

    open(unit=30, file="Output.txt", action="write", iostat=ioerr)
    if (ioerr /= 0) stop 1

    do i = 0, 999
        write(fname, '(A, I3.3, A)') "Fix", i, ".txt"
        open(unit = 40, file=fname, status="old", action="read", iostat=ioerr)
        if (ioerr /= 0) cycle
        read(40, *) d
        write(30, *) d
        close(40)
    end do
end program read_files
```

Comment: Since the OP is using gfortran I suggest using the `newunit` specifier instead of hard-coding file unit identifiers.

Comment: I'm not sure how 'new' the `newunit` statement is. He has asked about F77 to F95 -- so I didn't want to do anything that's outside this range.

Comment: For those using compilers without `newunit` support you may wish to look at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/newunit for a user implementation that can be used until your compiler updates.

Comment: apparently there is some thing wrong in my code after this line : `if (ioerr /= 0) cycle`. because it is ignored all the loops. program has been running correctly but  doesn't give any output. 
I don't know how this `newunit` works. i'm gonna search it, but know i guess this previous suggestion could work for me.

Comment: and also it would be fine if it can get the desired prefix `Fix`  from the user.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the version tags by users who just use a bunch of them without mentioning in the question they are version limited. Often they don't know much about new possibilities. But the newunit is a minor issue, it is fine with me as is.

Comment: @ShahramMaghami Why do you accept answer which does not work for you (yet)? Check your files are where they should be. Check the file names and paths. Check and print the value of `fname` so that we know which values are tried. The code in the answer looks OK.

Comment: I'm new here. not expert in the rules. The problem is with `Read(40,*) d` , that's encountered end file, run_time error F6501. even when my test file contain just one number (d).

Comment: Wow ! i made a stupid mistake ! build the file some where else which there was no input file there ! it works finally. thanks every body.